# Halide: How to explicitly schedule the anonymous reduction function, like sum?

Tags: convolution, halide

This is the convolution function wrote with Halide:

`output(x, y, z, n) = sum(Input(x * stride + r.x, y * stride + r.y, r.z, n) * Kernel(r.x, r.y, r.z, z));`

The html is like below:
[image]

I kinda expecting I can schedule sum, like:

`sum.compute_at(output, x_inner)`

so the sum can be more than only one element.

How can I do this with Halide?